# Check if a name from one array is found within another array and if not, push that name into a new array

Tags: javascript, arrays, compare

So I am trying to compare two arrays and push the string that isn't found into a new array. For example, I have array

```
= ["Bob", "Suzie", "Jake"]
```

and the array I'm passing into the function is

```
["Bob", "Mary", "Suzie"].
```

Since "Mary" isn't found in the first array, I want to push it into a new array.

--I know there are better ways to do this, but it has be with for loops and if statements.

```js
const array = ["Bob", "Suzie", "Jake"]

const findDifferentName = (arr) => {
  let newArr = [];
  for (const names of array) {
    for (const name of arr) {
      if (names !== name){
        newArr.push(name)
      }

findDifferentName(["Bob", "Mary", "Suzie"])
```

Comment: Open the console in your dev tools and read the error message `SyntaxError: missing } in compound statement`. I see four `{` and one `}`.

Comment: You can use [`includes`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes) method.

Comment: Why does it have to be for loops and if statements?

Answer (score 0):

Using the language features you've mentioned, you could do it something like this (I've assumed that the includes method is not allowed):

```js
const array = ["Bob", "Suzie", "Jake"]

const findDifferentName = (arr) => {
  let newArr = [];
  
  for (const name of arr) {
    let found = false;
    for (const notAllowed of array) {
      if (name === notAllowed) {
        found = true;
        break;
      }
    }
    
    if (!found) {
      newArr.push(name);
    }
  }
  
  return newArr;
}

const res = findDifferentName(["Bob", "Mary", "Suzie"]);

console.log(res);
```

If you're allowed to break things down using functions then you can make it a bit simpler to understand:

```js
const array = ["Bob", "Suzie", "Jake"];

const array_includes = (arr, subject) => {
  for (const item of arr)
    if (subject === item)
      return true;
  
  return false;
};

const findDifferentName = (arr) => {
  let newArr = [];
  
  for (const name of arr) 
    if (!array_includes(array, name))
      newArr.push(name);
  
  return newArr;
}

const res = findDifferentName(["Bob", "Mary", "Suzie"]);

console.log(res);
```